# Derivation of dynamic equation for continuous media

Tags: classical-mechanics, continuum-mechanics

I'm trying to understand Newton's law $\frac{\partial{\mathbf{j}}}{\partial{t}}=\mathcal{F}$ for continuous media. Here $\mathcal{F}$ is a force density, and the momentum density $\mathbf{j}$ is given by $\mu \mathbf{V}$, where $\mu$ is a local mass density and $\mathbf{V}$ is a local velocity field.  I have a couple of related questions.

I'm looking at the simplest example I can think of, namely a swarm of non-interacting particles released with no initial velocity in a constant gravitational field. This is just a one space-dimensional problem.  We take a coordinate system where $h$ is the independent variable, increasing in the downward direction, so that the gravitational force points in the positive direction.  The force density $\mathcal{F}$ is therefore $\mu \mathbf g$, with $\mathbf g$ positive.

Assume that the particles are released at a constant rate $\rho$ (measured in units of mass per time).  Assume they are released at position $h=0$.  So at any fixed position $h$, $\rho$ units of mass pass by that position in any unit time.  Since the rate of mass going past the fixed position is exactly the momentum density $\mathbf{j}$, we see that $\mathbf{j}\left(h,t\right) = \rho$, a constant. But this can't be right, since the partial time derivative of $\mathbf{j}$ must equal $\mathcal{F}$.  I'm obviously misunderstanding something rather badly.  What am I doing wrong?

The more general question has to do with the form of the equation $\frac{\partial{\mathbf{j}}}{\partial{t}}=\mathcal{F}$ itself.  (I've adopted this form from the usage in Mizushima's book Theoretical Physics, although he does not state it so explicitly.) I would have thought that the equation would be $\frac{d\mathbf{j}}{dt}=\mathcal{F}$, but this does not help with the issue above.  The form that does seem to lead to the correct result is actually $\mu \frac{d\mathbf{V}}{dt}= \mathcal{F}$, since $\frac{d\mathbf{V}}{dt}=\frac{\partial{\mathbf{V}}}{\partial t} + \mathbf{V} \frac{\partial{\mathbf{V}}}{\partial h} = \mathbf g $, but I don't see why this form should be true in general. (Here I make use of $\mathbf{V}=\sqrt{2gh}$.  We also have $\mu = \frac{\rho}{\sqrt{2gh}}$.)

In fairness, I should say that Mizushima treats the general problem and does derive  $\frac{\partial{\mathbf{j}}}{\partial{t}} = \mu \left( \frac{\partial{\mathbf{V}}}{\partial{t}} + \left(\mathbf{V}\cdot \nabla \right) \mathbf{V} \right)$, but only by suppressing a term that would contribute boundary terms after integration. Setting this to $\mathcal{F}$ in the one dimensional problem above also leads to the correct answer, but I don't see the justification for ignoring that term here.

I'd appreciate any help you can give in straightening me out on all this.

Comment: You seem to be missing the vector component in the current? It looks like a scalar now, that does not look right? Aha, perhaps 1 is the basis. Do the particles have speed 1?

Comment: @Emil, yes, you right about the vector notation .. since this is a one-dimensional problem I failed to differentiate between the vector and the component of the vector.  So the basis here really should be 1.  I should probably just suppress the vector notation completely for the example.  Sorry it is misleading.  The particles are acted on by gravity, so they are accelerating at the constant rate g (where g is constant here).  So speed as a function of position h is just V = \sqrt(2 g h),  as I state above.  Thank you.